# How can I detect if the mouse on an object currently?

Tags: python, objects

I want to do something when the mouse moves over an object, so I want to know how to detect if the mouse moves over that object?

Comment: Since ray casting doesn't work on non-mesh objects like cameras, curves, etc. This is an operator that works on all visible object types: 
 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52142/get-curve-under-mouse-position/288212#288212

Comment: Yes, you have a good complementation !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ray cast for that. For example, the following will detect everytime the mouse moves to a new screen X/Y location, throw out a ray from under your mouse and return some information about what object it hit.
See here for more info: https://docs.blender.org/api/3.5/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.ray_cast

`hit` is a boolean that returns `True` if an object is detected under the mouse coordinates

```
   def modal(self, context, event):
    
          if event.type == "MOUSEMOVE":
          if event.mouse_prev_x != event.mouse_x or event.mouse_prev_y != event.mouse_y:
    
          hit, face_location, face_normal, face_index, face_object, face_matrix = self.cast_ray(context, event)
          if hit:
                if face_object.type == 'MESH':
                      print("face_object", face_object)
                      print("face_location", face_location)
                      print("face_normal", face_normal)
                      print("face_index", face_index)
                      print("face_matrix", face_matrix)
    
    
    
    def cast_ray(self, context, event):
    
          # cast ray from mouse location, return data from ray
          scene = context.scene
          region = context.region
          rv3d = context.region_data
          coord = event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y
          viewlayer = context.view_layer.depsgraph
          # get the ray from the viewport and mouse
          view_vector = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d(region, rv3d, coord)
          ray_origin = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_origin_3d(region, rv3d, coord)
    
          hit, location, normal, index, object, matrix = scene.ray_cast(viewlayer, ray_origin, view_vector)
          return hit, location, normal, index, object, matrix
```

Comment: oh yes !  How you know this api !  That's very userful.